# how to get the next td elements from the same tr in HTML, vba

Tags: vba

i am new in vba. i wants yours opinion in how to get the value from the next td elements by using the condition. lets say, if the elements from the previous td is true then we will take the next td link for download the file.

in the html, this is on one tr and 3 td like this:

TABLE 1. INVENTORIES | Link download.xls | Link download.zip

---

this is my coding:

```
Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim tdobj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim trobj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement  
Set tr = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
For Each trobj In tr
    Set td = trobj.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each tdobj In td
        If (Trim(tdobj.innerText) Like "TABLE 1. INVENTORIES*") Then
            "take link download .xls here"
        End If
    Next
Next
```

it is possible to get? i get the table inventories but i stuck on how to get the "Link download.xls". if there any suggestion, please let me know guys..

Comment: Use nextSibling property to obtain the next item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

As Santosh said in the comments:

> Use nextSibling property to obtain the next item in the list.